# Windows Server 2012 RDS Unable to publish RemoteApps. Unable to get list of programs

Tags: windows-server-2012, remoteapp, rds, web

I have `RD Web Access`, `RD Connection Broker`, `RD Session host` and a collection set up. When I try to publish Remote Apps to the collection through the Server Manager it just loops over and over when trying to get list of available applications. I've been letting it run for over 24 hours but no application gets listed.

I can't see any error logs either.

It loops on `Retrieving a list of remoteapp programs that are available for publishing`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.

Files where missing from the `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu` folder.